Spurious correlation of ratios in per capita analyses
I'm trying to figure out how the spurious correlation of ratios impacts analyses where the variables are per capita measures.
Suppose I have a regression
$$
\text{GDP per capita}_{it} = \alpha + \beta \cdot \text{Carbon Dioxide per capita}_{it}
$$
$$
\ln(\text{GDP per capita}_{it}) = \alpha + \beta \cdot \ln(\text{Carbon Dioxide per capita}_{it})
$$
$$
\ln(\text{GDP}) = \alpha + \beta \cdot \ln(\text{Carbon Dioxide}) + \gamma \cdot \ln(\text{Population})
$$
If I find that beta is significant in the first regression, then is it likely that that's a spurious correlation? What about the second? Third?
A lot of the per capita measures make it so that it's much more easy to interpret, but I'm wondering what kind of fix I should be using.

It seems to me that it would only be spurious if you were actually interested in the raw data (not per capita). But I think you are likely to be interested in the per capita data.  But I'm curious enough about this to add a bounty if it doesn't get a good answer in 2 days.

Spurious correlations of this type arrise when you have three independent variables $x,y,z$ and then make a comparison with two ratio's $\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z}$.

If the analogy is exactly the same then in your case this would be analogous to
$$\begin{array}{}
x &=& \text{total GDP} \\
y &=& \text{total CO}_2 \\
z &=& \text{population size}
\end{array}$$
and then make two ratios
$$\text{GDP per capita} = \frac{\text{total GDP}}{\text{population size}} \\ \text{Carbon Dioxide per capita} = \frac{\text{total CO}_2}{\text{population size}}$$

You could say that this analogy does not apply, or is more subtle. These ratio variables are more like an averages of a sum of individuals. The $x,y$ are not independent from $z$. The higher the population the higher the GDP and CO2 production.
With these ratios it is closer to the situation that $x' = x/z$ and $y' = y/z$ are independent variables (if GDP and CO2 would be unrelated) and the spurious correlation arrises from a product instead of ratio $x = x' \cdot z$ and $y = y' \cdot z$ will be correlated.
This can make it difficult to compare variables. In which relative units should variables be considered independent in the case of a null effect? For example, is the CO2 to be compared with population size or land area?

In a recent news article I saw this situation arrise in a ranking of countries by emissions of nitrogen compounds by land area. Comparing countries in rankings is always tricky. If nitrogen is generated based on 'per population' (the more people, the more traffic/transport, agricultural, and industry), then the relationship with 'per area' will be prone to spurious relationships. (Of course the nature is impacted based on nitrogen per area, and the nature doesn't care whether the relationship is spurious or not.)

https://nos.nl/artikel/2307260-kan-de-ruime-duitse-stikstofnorm-ook-in-nederland

Sometimes it can be difficult to know what the right expression of the variables is to make a neutral comparison. An example is the comparison of the number of medals at the olympics. Medal count relates to GDP and population, but you can not correct for them by using a ratio because countries also have a limited number of entries.   Olympics - Hungary Has Double Digit Lead in Gold? (Population Relative)


